# access rails url helper from deface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am including Spree to an existing site. I am changing the spree header with Deface to render my site's header instead. Therefore I use the following Deface DSL code

```
<!-- replace_contents "header[data-hook]" -->
<%= render :partial => "layouts/my_site_header.html.erb" %>
```

And inside `_my_site_header.html.erb` I have something like this

```
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Game", game_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Community", community_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Which gives me the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `home_path' for #<#<Class:0x8a73c20>:0x8af0e58>
```

I understood that the code get executed by Deface in the Spree scope, thus my site's url helpers are undefined. I could solve this using the full method name like `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.home_path`

However, I don't really feel like adding this for all of my links. Isn't there a way to tell Spree to include the url helpers of my site? Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a shorter version which you can use from [Rails::Engine](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) called main_app.

```
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", main_app.home_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Game", main_app.game_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Community", main_app.community_path %></li>
</ul>
```

I would highly recommend using this to avoid conflicts between your application and Spree (such as your app home vs. Spree's home).

Comment: thanks a lot :) such a small helper is okay to add everywhere for me