# How to override spree users api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, spree

I have integrated spree with my application. I have overridden `spree-user` model to `user` model. I am trying to override api/users to come to my `UsersController` but instead everytime when I make a call to `/api/users/`, the control goes to `Spree::Api::UsersController`. I have the following route for user

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

But still my routes are overridden. What changes should I do to route `/api/users/` to my local controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend` in **routes.rb**:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  namespace :api do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

Alternatively, try appending `main_app` when you call the route in your view code, eg:

```
main_app.api_users_path
```

Not sure if you have tried that already but hopefully it helps. You can read more at the SO threads below:

- [Adding Routes to Rails' Spree E-Commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce)
- [How to add new view to Ruby on Rails Spree commerce app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498208/how-to-add-new-view-to-ruby-on-rails-spree-commerce-app)
- [access rails url helper from deface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294079/access-rails-url-helper-from-deface)